# What does the 9090:grpc/TCP notation mean?

Tags: kubernetes, port

In Lens, the microservice has port 9090:grpc/TCP.
What does it mean?

For example, 9090:20033/TCP means port forwarding grpc 9090 to 20033.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`9090:grpc/TCP` notation means a network endpoint that is listening on `port 9090` for incoming gRPC connections over TCP.

**Yes, your example is correct.** port 9090:20033/TCP, which means that the gRPC service is listening on port 9090. When you port forward grpc 9090 to 20033, you are creating a tunnel from port 9090 on your local machine to port 20033 on the remote machine. This allows you to access the gRPC service on the remote machine as if it were running on your local machine.

You can refer to this [document](https://www.auditmypc.com/tcp-port-9090.asp) for more information.

**Edit 1:**

`9090:20033/TCP` notates **port forwarding** port 9090 to port 20033 on the TCP protocol.

`9090:grpc/TCP` means **no port forwarding**. The word "grpc" is simply a **label** to indicate that port 9090 is being used for the gRPC protocol. An empty space would be interpreted as a separator between the port and the protocol, which would cause the port forwarding to fail.

Comment: That is, 9090:grpc/TCP means no port forwarding?   
And the word "grpc" is indicated simply so that there is no empty space like 9090:/TCP?

Comment: I have updated the answer under the Edit 1 section. Can you please look into it and let me know if it is useful.